# How to display all words in a table in Latex

Tags: tables

I have 96 word pairs, which i want to present in a latex document, the problem is that currently not all the word pairs show up. Please take a look at the image.

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{3cm}}


\title{Did You Hear What I Said?}
\author{test (Test) }
\date{September 2016}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Shows the word 96 words pairs}
\begin{tabular}{l | c |c| r}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Word Pairs} \\
\hline
\label{tab:wordtable}

Words A & Words B\\
\hline \hline
veal    &   feel    \\
bean    &   peen    \\
gin &   chin    \\
dint    &   tint    \\
zoo &   sue \\
dune    &   tune    \\
voal    &   foal    \\
goat    &   coat    \\
zed &   said    \\
dense   &   tense   \\
vast    &   fast    \\
gaff    &   caff    \\
vault   &   fault   \\
daunt   &   taunt   \\
jock    &   chock   \\
bond    &   pond    \\
meat    &   beat    \\
need    &   deed    \\
mitt    &   bit \\
nip &   dip \\
moot    &   boot    \\
news    &   dues    \\
moan    &   bone    \\
note    &   dote    \\
mend    &   bend    \\
neck    &   deck    \\
mad &   bad \\
nab &   dab \\
moss    &   boss    \\
gnaw    &   daw \\
mom &   bomb    \\
knock   &   dock    \\
vee &   bee \\
sheet   &   cheat   \\
vill    &   bill    \\
thick   &   tick    \\
foo &   pooh    \\
shoes   &   choose  \\
those   &   doze    \\
though  &   dough   \\
then    &   den \\
fence   &   pence   \\
than    &   dan \\
shad    &   chad    \\
thong   &   tong    \\
shaw    &   chaw    \\
von &   bon \\
vox &   box \\
zee &   thee    \\
cheep   &   keep    \\
jilt    &   gilt    \\
sing    &   thing   \\
juice   &   goose   \\
chew    &   coo \\
joe &   go  \\
sole    &   thole   \\
jest    &   guest   \\
chair   &   care    \\
jab &   gab \\
sank    &   thank   \\
jaws    &   gauze   \\
saw &   thaw    \\
jot &   got \\
chop    &   cop \\
weed    &   reed    \\
peak    &   teak    \\
bid &   did \\
fin &   thin    \\
moon    &   noon    \\
pool    &   tool    \\
bowl    &   dole    \\
fore    &   thor    \\
met &   net \\
pent    &   tent    \\
bank    &   dank    \\
fad &   thad    \\
fought  &   thought \\
bong    &   dong    \\
wad &   rod \\
pot &   tot \\
yield   &   wield   \\
key &   tea \\
hit &   fit \\
gill    &   dill    \\
coop    &   poop    \\
you &   rue \\
ghost   &   boast   \\
show    &   so  \\
keg &   peg \\
yen &   wren    \\
gat &   bat \\
shag    &   sag \\
yawl    &   wall    \\
caught  &   taught  \\
hop &   fop \\
got &   dot \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Well, seems if your table is longer than the page. Three possibilities: split it into two tables, use `longtable` to enable pagebreaking or use a smaller fontsize.

Comment: That said, why does your table have 4 columns if there are only two words?

Comment: @samcarter While splitting into two `table`s  is possible, perhaps you meant to split into two `tabular`s, since those could be placed side by side in a single table.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Unfortunately I did not think of this possibility. That's a great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `tabular` or a `table` can break across a page boundary.  So here, I just take your long `tabular` and break it up into 3 smaller ones, placing them side by side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{3cm}}


\title{Did You Hear What I Said?}
\author{test (Test) }
\date{September 2016}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Shows the word 96 words pairs}
\label{tab:wordtable}
\begin{tabular}{|l | c |c| r}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Word Pairs} \\
\hline
Words A & Words B\\
\hline \hline
veal    &   feel    \\
bean    &   peen    \\
gin &   chin    \\
dint    &   tint    \\
zoo &   sue \\
dune    &   tune    \\
voal    &   foal    \\
goat    &   coat    \\
zed &   said    \\
dense   &   tense   \\
vast    &   fast    \\
gaff    &   caff    \\
vault   &   fault   \\
daunt   &   taunt   \\
jock    &   chock   \\
bond    &   pond    \\
meat    &   beat    \\
need    &   deed    \\
mitt    &   bit \\
nip &   dip \\
moot    &   boot    \\
news    &   dues    \\
moan    &   bone    \\
note    &   dote    \\
mend    &   bend    \\
neck    &   deck    \\
mad &   bad \\
nab &   dab \\
moss    &   boss    \\
gnaw    &   daw \\
mom &   bomb    \\
knock   &   dock    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{.4cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l | c |c| r}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Word Pairs} \\
\hline
Words A & Words B\\
\hline \hline
vee &   bee \\
sheet   &   cheat   \\
vill    &   bill    \\
thick   &   tick    \\
foo &   pooh    \\
shoes   &   choose  \\
those   &   doze    \\
though  &   dough   \\
then    &   den \\
fence   &   pence   \\
than    &   dan \\
shad    &   chad    \\
thong   &   tong    \\
shaw    &   chaw    \\
von &   bon \\
vox &   box \\
zee &   thee    \\
cheep   &   keep    \\
jilt    &   gilt    \\
sing    &   thing   \\
juice   &   goose   \\
chew    &   coo \\
joe &   go  \\
sole    &   thole   \\
jest    &   guest   \\
chair   &   care    \\
jab &   gab \\
sank    &   thank   \\
jaws    &   gauze   \\
saw &   thaw    \\
jot &   got \\
chop    &   cop \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{.4cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l | c |c| r}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Word Pairs} \\
\hline
Words A & Words B\\
\hline \hline
weed    &   reed    \\
peak    &   teak    \\
bid &   did \\
fin &   thin    \\
moon    &   noon    \\
pool    &   tool    \\
bowl    &   dole    \\
fore    &   thor    \\
met &   net \\
pent    &   tent    \\
bank    &   dank    \\
fad &   thad    \\
fought  &   thought \\
bong    &   dong    \\
wad &   rod \\
pot &   tot \\
yield   &   wield   \\
key &   tea \\
hit &   fit \\
gill    &   dill    \\
coop    &   poop    \\
you &   rue \\
ghost   &   boast   \\+
show    &   so  \\
keg &   peg \\
yen &   wren    \\
gat &   bat \\
shag    &   sag \\
yawl    &   wall    \\
caught  &   taught  \\
hop &   fop \\
got &   dot \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]